# Click vs touch on mobile devices in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

When comparing the following 2 event listeners:

```
$("#button").click(myFunc);
```

and

```
$("#button").on("touchstart", myFunc);
```

Why is a touchscreen device's response to the click event slower than the touch event, what determines this i.e the order of operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a click until your finger releases its pressure. The `click` is a consequence of `touchend`, not `touchstart`.

Most often there's also a delay between the `touchend` and the `click` so that a double tap can be detected (then a `click` event isn't sent).